# How to read a file with a filter dialogue in dart?

Tags: file-io, dart

I only find the file reading API on the server side. How should I read a file on the client side, with a filter dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an HTML file input with an accept attribute to restrict the type of file:

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
```

Then you can listen for the user selecting the file with a change event:

```dart
Element fileSelect = query("#fileSelect");
fileSelect.onChange.listen( (event) => print('${event.target.files[0].name}'));
```

`event.target.files` is a [FileList](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/FileList.html) object.